# jQuery and setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have the following code:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
setTimeout($('#loading').fadeIn('slow'), 9999);
            });
```

which should slowly fade in the loading element after 9999 miliseconds but instead it fades it in straight away... why?

Can anyone help. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to do what you want, you have to wrap the jQuery stuff in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#loading').fadeIn('slow');
}, 9999);
```

The `setTimeout` function (and `setInterval` as well) must be told what to do after the delay. And there are only three ways to tell it what to do:

1. With a string of JavaScript that it must `eval`:

   ```
   setTimeout('$("#loading").fadeIn("slow")', 9999);
   ```

   Because this uses `eval`, and can get pretty ugly, it's not recommended. But it works fine.
2. With a function **reference**:

   ```
   var test = function () {
       $('#loading').fadeIn('slow');
   };

   setTimeout(test, 9999);
   ```

   Note that I didn't do `setTimeout(test(), 9999)`. I just gave it the name of the function.
3. With an anonymous function that you construct on the fly, which is what I did in the first code block above.

If you try to do something like `setTimeout(test(), 9999)`, then the browser will **first** execute `test()`, and then give the **return value** to `setTimeout`. So in your attempt...

```
setTimeout($('#loading').fadeIn('slow'), 9999);
```

...the browser was executing that jQuery stuff, fading in the `#loading` element, and then giving whatever `fadeIn` returns to `setTimeout`. As it happens, the `fadeIn` function returns a jQuery object. But setTimeout doesn't know what to do with objects, so nothing would happen after the 9999 millisecond delay.

Answer (score 4):

The settimeout() function is from javascript and takes a function as an argument.

Best choice would be to use jQuery's builtin delay() function:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('#loading').delay(9999).fadeIn('slow');
 });
```

More information/exemples: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` accepts a function as first parameter - you are currently passing a jQuery selector, which immediately gets evaluated which executes the `fadeIn` operation. Instead pass in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $('#loading').fadeIn('slow'), 9999);
}, 9999);
```

Comment: Small error on the grammar, you should edit to make your answer clearer to non-js-addicts eyes who corrected this on their own =)

Otherwise, Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery's .delay().

$('#loading').delay(9999).fadeIn('slow');