# Stop Running javascript code on jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i stop runing code?

For example when  run 5 lines code. stop 3 second and then its continue. on jquery

Comment: Google `setTimeout`, it's asynchronous, although that's how your code should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery and setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085925/jquery-and-settimeout)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/javascript-sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   //code paused
}, 3000);
```

3000 = 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds.