# jQuery setTimeout on toggle class

Tags: jquery, toggle, settimeout

I have got a button that only appears when it hits a certain media query. Now it works fine, the button appears, clicking the button will reveal the sidenav. Clicking again closes the menu.

My problem is this - I've got a class that toggle with it as well, called 'open'. This enables me to use a different icon to represent open and close. But i need a delay on the toggle class so the icon doesn't change until the menu bar has closed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        /* prepend category button */
        $('.side-bar').before('<div id="button"><p class="sidebar-button"> Menu </p></div>'); //insert html for menu button

            $(".sidebar-button").click(function() { //click menu button and do..

                setTimeout(function(){ //i added this..

              $(".side-bar").slideToggle(); //toggle sidebar
              $(this).toggleClass("open"); // toggle class on button for 'open'
            });
        },5000); // other part of the seTimeout
    });
```

Whats the best way to achieve this? Live example for the purpose of this question: http://jsfiddle.net/rXt39/2/

**EDIT**

**This might help someone looking for a similar thing. I found a solution here:**

[jQuery and setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085925/jquery-and-settimeout?rq=1)

**Note:** I ended up changing my code on the answer below. It's now working perfectly.

Comment: using a setTimeout will work only when the toggle animation is set to be the same as the timeout, if a person has a menu with more or less items then it will not work. Thats why you can set a callback to execute at the moment the first function finishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a callback for the menu to toggleClass the icon when its finished

```
      $reference = $(this)

      $(".side-bar").slideToggle(function(){
            $reference.toggleClass("open");           
      });
```

I added a .open class in the CSS to turn the word menu yellow while expanded.

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rXt39/6/)

Comment: This didnt work when i look at the class toggle in the source. The class isn't being applied? If i understand correctly, my solution is flawed because if my menu had more items and the time the toggle took to finish increased, the icon would be out of sync again?

Comment: i just added a class open to show it works, when the menu word will turn yellow when the menu item is ready. And yes, with more or less items the menu will end up out of sync